# Include PPBootStrap.php in symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, paypal

i have added Paypal SDK files to the vendor folder. But in order to use the SDK classes in my symfony2 project i need to require "PPBootStrap.php".

Where exactly should i add the code to require this file and how?
In composer.json or autoload.php

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? in 2.0 I would recomend adding it in autoload.php, but in later versions the autoloading is handled by composer. Also, if the SDK does not use namespaced PHP, remember that you will need to add a \ (to specify global namespace) before any SDK functions/classes you use.

Comment: i have idea regarding the namespace issue. can you please help me with adding the PPBootStrap.php in the composer(since im using symfony2.1 )  and updating the composer thereafter.i dont want other bundles to be update while running `composer update`